# SSRS Column Chart Design Returning values in a format different from SSRS -SSAS Query Designer

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have an SSAS cube Measure Group with Multiple Measures that I am attempting to return on one SSRS report and reflect the values using a ssrs column chart.

My Measure Group (Patients).

Measures:

- PatientsOnMeds
- PatientOnRelapse
- PatientsCounseld
- TotalNumberOfPatientsRegisterd
- NewlyRegisteredPatients
- HealthPersonelTrainef

Demension:
Time (Year) :filtered to 2012 & 2013

In my SSRS query designer I have filtered the above Measures with Time Dimesion year 2012 & 2013

and the data is returned as :

```
|Year|PatientsOnMeds|PatientOnRelapse|TotalNumberOfPatientsRegisterd|NewlyRegisteredPatients|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012 | 700          | 526            |  25                          | 456
2013 | 245          | 245            |  15                          | 70
```

Now the problem is when I return this data on the column Chart it's in messed up mesh

On the chart Data:

-Values :Measures

-Series Group: Dimension

The report values are returned in multiple columns for each value segmented by year i.e year 2012,Year 2013.

I want a single column for each Measure (value) for each single year and The chart axis to reflect the measures(values)

instead of grouping values according to series group.

instead the legend returns:

```
-Year A -PatientsOnMeds
-Year A -PatientOnRelapse
-Year B -PatientsOnMeds
-Year B -PatientOnRelapse
```

I would like the legend to reflect on -Year A,Year B in color code that will be highlighted in the column values.

Please point me in the right course if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would "move" the Series Group definition to be a Category Group.

In practical terms this means creating a Category Group with the same definition as your Series Group, then deleting your Series Group.

Comment: Mike,That did not work either.In actual I want the legend to show:

-2012

-2013

And the bottom axis to show:

PatientsOnMeds
PatientOnRelapse
PatientsCounseld
TotalNumberOfPatientsRegisterd
NewlyRegisteredPatients
HealthPersonelTrained

Indicating in color code for Year 2012 and Year 2013.

Comment: In that case I think you need to alter the MDX query to unpivot your result set into multiple rows.  I think you need a "Measure" column that returns values like PatientsOnMeds PatientOnRelapse etc.  That would become your Category Group.

Comment: Thanks,sounds like a start.Thank you so much for your input.